# Selenium Java - Webpage Dialog - Close Dialog and Quit (Only if it is displayed)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, exception, modal-dialog

I have a doubt with a **Webpage Dialog**:

The situation is the next: I try to log in a login page with wrong credentials, so I use any data in the login page. With this, is displayed a **Webpage Dialog** telling that the username or password is invalid.

This message is a Webpage Dialog, so I'm using the next code to close it:

```
Robot robot = null;

try {
    robot = new Robot();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is working, but when I put a condition like the next:

```
try {
    robot = new Robot();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally{
    driver.quit();
}
```

This is not working any when I move the driver.quit(); to any position in the code.
I just want to close the driver when this **Webpage Dialog** is present, just in this situation.

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to close the driver only when Webpage Dialog is present, you should write driver.quit(); in the end of try block.

```
try {
    robot = new Robot();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    driver.quit();
} catch (AWTException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: When the password is invalid the river.quit(); at that point of the code is working, but when the password is OK, the system still closing the driver.

Comment: 1) are you deleted finally block? 2) if login-pass is good is  Webpage Dialog is present?

Comment: I deleted the finnaly block, because it always closes the driver with or without the display of the Webpage Dialog. If the login is valid the Webpage is not present anymore.

Comment: i understand you. 1) you can don't use robot, but try to use `Alert alert = webDriver.switchTo().alert(); alert.accept();` 2) if  first will not work you can make some that will understand have you a Webpage Dialog, if yes make Robot clicks and then driver.quit();. Now your code make Robot clicks in all cases/

Comment: Actually it doesn't work, because this is not an alert, but a Webpage Dialog.